# graphClient.Directory.AdministrativeUnits

Tags: azure

I am trying to get AdministrativeUnits using the Microsoft.Graph.Api, but when I write the following lines I get error on Directory.AdministrativeUnits

```
var administrativeUnits = await graphClient.Directory.AdministrativeUnits.Request().GetAsync();
```

The graphClient.Directory doesnt have AdministrativeUnits what am I missing?

from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/administrativeunit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: The api tool is provided in the document, try to call the api to see what the result is? This requires you to log in first.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSMby.png